# add ciphers to curl runnning on amazon AMI

Tags: linux, ssl, curl

I have shell scripts that run curl commands against an ssl secured rest api.

Everything was working fine until they added a new firewall that block unknown ciphers.

Now i'm trying to specify the cipher in every curl command using --cipher 'CIPHER_NAME' the problem is that any cipher i try (the one i need is "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA") gets me the same error: 
* Unknown cipher in list: THE_NAME_I_USED

How can I "install" the ciphers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I "install" the ciphers?

You don't. Which ciphers are available and which syntax is used to specify the ciphers depends on the underlying TLS library. To get to the proper syntax just read the [man page of curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) which states:

> --ciphers <list of ciphers>
>   ... The list of ciphers must specify valid ciphers. **Read up on SSL cipher
>   list details on this URL:**
>    https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html

And if you actually follow the URL you get to the details of the syntax. The exact syntax depends on the underlying TLS library (which you get when calling `curl -V`). In case of OpenSSL the cipher in question would be `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`.

Note that it might be that your curl is compiled against a TLS library which does not support the cipher you want. In this case you might need to link (i.e. recompile) curl with a newer version of the library or a different library which supports this cipher.

Comment: @hanshenrik: looking at the source of `Configure` (there is no `configure` in lower case, only `config`) this is not how it works. You can for example `--enable-ecdh` or `--disable-ec` or similar but there is no way to enable a single specific cipher as you claim.

Comment: turns out i work with NSS and my cipher is "rsa_aes_256_cbc_sha_256" thanks for the guidelines!

Comment: @Osher: `rsa_aes_256_cbc_sha_256` is not the same as `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` but would be instead `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`.  These ciphers differ in key exchange (RSA vs. ECDHE) and MAC (SHA-256 vs. SHA-1). `ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_sha` instead is the one matching `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`.

Comment: I tried the one matching my exact cipher demand, and it didn't work. then i tried that one and it did, maybe the firewall guys gave me the wrong one, but since my scripts now work, im happy :)